# Integrability of a random variable

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I got a little bit confused about the definition of 'integrability' of a random variable.
Recall the definition:

**Definition.** Let $(\Omega , {\mathfrak{M}}, \mathbb{P}) $ be a probability space. A random variable $X$ defined on $\Omega$ is *integrable* if $\int_{\Omega} |X|  d\mathbb{P} < \infty$.

I am not sure about the following, but it seems to me that:
$X$ is integrable if and only if $\int_{\Omega} X  d\mathbb{P} < \infty$.

Is this true?

Of course, if $X$ is integrable then $\int_{\Omega} X  d\mathbb{P} < \infty$; this is the obvious implication. But the reverse implication also seems true to me. Can someone confirm or disprove this claim?

Comment: Let $X$take the value $-n$ with probability $\frac  c{n^{2}}$ where $c=\frac 6 {\pi^{2}}$ Then $EX=-\infty$.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum a_n <\infty$ and $\sum |a_n|<\infty$ are not equivalent?

Comment: I guess what you want to say is that $EX$ exist as  a real number (not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$) if and only if $E|X|<\infty$. This statement is correct.